# Preencher objeto em Swift usando dados de um return JSON

Tags: json, ios, swift

Tenho um webapi que retorna uma lista de provas:

```
{
  "Provas": [
    {
      "Codigo": "11111111111",
      "Disciplina": {
        "Codigo": "111111",
        "Nome": "SOCIOLOGIA E EDUCAÃ‡ÃƒO"
      },
      "Tipo": "SUB",
      "Correcao": "2016-07-01T14:33:33.383",
      "Exame": false,
      "Sub": true
    },
    {
      "Codigo": "22222222222",
      "Disciplina": {
        "Codigo": "333333",
        "Nome": "EDUCAÃ‡ÃƒO DE JOVENS E ADULTOS: FUNDAMENTOS E METODOLOGIA"
      },
      "Tipo": "SUB",
      "Correcao": "2016-06-30T11:53:11.207",
      "Exame": false,
      "Sub": true
    },
    {
      "Codigo": "333333333333",
      "Disciplina": {
        "Codigo": "444444",
        "Nome": "METODOLOGIA E PRÃTICA DO ENSINO DA HISTÃ“RIA E GEOGRAFIA"
      },
      "Tipo": "BIMESTRAL",
      "Correcao": "2016-06-29T09:42:29.097",
      "Exame": false,
      "Sub": false
    }
  ]
}
```

E criei uma classe chamada Prova

```
import Foundation

class Prova
{
    let codigo:String
    let tipo:String
    let dtcorrecao:NSDate
    let disciplina:Disciplina

    init(codigo:String, tipo:String, dtcorrecao:NSDate, disciplina:Disciplina)
    {
        self.codigo = codigo
        self.tipo = tipo
        self.dtcorrecao = dtcorrecao
        self.disciplina = disciplina
    }
}
```

e outra chama Disciplina

```
import Foundation

class Disciplina
{
    let codigo:String
    let nomedisciplina:String

    init(codigo:String, nomedisciplina:String)
    {
        self.codigo = codigo
        self.nomedisciplina = nomedisciplina
    }
}
```

Gostaria de saber como converter esses dados para uma lista de Provas conforme minha classe?, preciso alterar alguma coisa na construção dessas classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Uma opção usando framework open source é o [Object Mapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper):**

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper //importa o framework

class Prova: Mappable // adota o protocolo
{
    // declara as variaveis
    var codigo: String!
    var tipo: String!
    var dtcorrecao: NSDate!
    var disciplina: Disciplina!
    var sub: Bool!
    var exame: Bool!

    // chama o inicializador que mapeia o JSON
    required init?(_ map: Map) {}

    // mapeia a classe conforme os campos do JSON
    func mapping(map: Map) {
      codigo      <- map["Codigo"]
      tipo        <- map["Tipo"]
      dtcorrecao  <- map["Correcao"]
      disciplina  <- map["Disciplina"]
      sub         <- map["Sub"]
      exame       <- map["Exame"]
    }
}
```

Disciplina:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

class Disciplina: Mappable
{
    var codigo: String!
    var nomedisciplina: String!

    required init?(_ map: Map) {}

    func mapping(map: Map) {
       codigo           <- map["Codigo"]
       nomedisciplina   <- map["Nome"]
    }
}
```

Provas: (precisamos mapear esta chave que esta no topo do JSON)

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

class Provas: Mappable
{
    var provas: [Prova]!

    required init?(_ map: Map) {}

    func mapping(map: Map) {
       provas           <- map["Provas"]
    }
}
```

---

**Pra criar um objeto mapeado:**

*Depois de ter requisitado o JSON* basta chamar

```
let provas = Mapper<Provas>().map(JSONString)
```

Comment: Cara funcionou direitinho obrigado.

Comment: Porém como ficaria isso dentro de uma TableViewControllor??, Criei uma func para chamar esse dados via Alamofire, fiz todo o codigo da table view mas não carrega na tableview

Comment: Como você já tem o array de `Provas` é só passar ele dentro da TableViewController caso não esteja nela e chamar o `reloadData()`:

Comment: Estava esquecendo do reloadData(), agora deu certo valeu!!!

Comment: Como faço para guardar esse objeto Prova numa sessão (NSUserDefaults)

Comment: possuo uma situaçao pouco diferente  meu json nao tem um titulo em cima ela ja vem desta forma [{
    "id": "1",
    "description": "TESTE 1",
    "live": "https://www.example1.com/live",
    "thumb": "https://www.example1.com/thumb",
    "online": true },
    {"id": "2",
    "description": "TESTE 2",
    "live": "https://www.example2.com/live",
    "thumb": "https://www.example2.com/thumb",
    "online": true
}]